# Friendly ID Random Url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, friendly-id

I am using friendly for my site, and at the moment I have it displaying the title in the url

ie: `/articles/hello-world`

but say when i create the page, it generates a random number, to avoid duplication
so

ie:  `/articles/75475848`

I know if i get rid of friendly id it will display numbers but 
it will be

/articles/1

/articles/2

etc...

Basically how do i get it to show `/articles/23456789(random number)` instead of `/articles/hello-world`

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It seems that generating a UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) for each article might be a good solution for you.

The Ruby standard library gives us a UUID-generating method, so all you need to do is create a database field and then use a `before_save` callback to give each article its own UUID. Like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_uuid

  def set_uuid
    self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid if self.uuid.nil?
  end
end
```

**Edit:** No need for external dependencies as per @olleolleolle's comment!

Comment: Or in the standard library - [SecureRandom::uuid](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid).

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer to use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the FriendlyID docs:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :name_and_location
  def name_and_location
    "#{name} from #{location}"
  end
end

bob = Person.create! :name => "Bob Smith", :location => "New York City"
bob.friendly_id #=> "bob-smith-from-new-york-city"
```

So, if you provide a method for `friendly_id` that generates a random number that method will be used to generate the slug instead.